# cannot create a nested Ubuntu 20.04 image model on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I cannot create a nested Ubuntu 20.04 image model on Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

I created a project in Google Cloud Platforn (GCP) and tried to create a nested Ubuntu 20.04 image model with the following command, but it returned an error and could not be created.

Command:

```
gcloud compute images create nested-ubuntu-focal-v2 --source-image-family=ubuntu-2004-lts --source-image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --licenses https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vmoptions/global/licenses/enable-vmx
```

Error:

```
(gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/vmoptions/global/licenses/enable-vmx' was not found
```

I have confirmed that the resource exists in GCP.

```
username@cloudshell:~ (my-project-ev-ng)$ gcloud compute images list
---snip---
NAME: ubuntu-minimal-2004-focal-v20230303
PROJECT: ubuntu-os-cloud
FAMILY: ubuntu-minimal-2004-lts
DEPRECATED:
STATUS: READY
---snip---
```

By the way, I did the same work on a different project in February of this year and was able to run the commands without problems then. Is it not possible to create the same image on multiple projects? If anyone knows a solution, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks for your help inadvance!